# How to center align div Without a set width

Tags: html, width, jquery-masonry, css

I'm creating a Masonry style page layout and I'm trying to find a way of centering the tiles when the page is not at full size.  What I have at the moment is like:

```
| [ TILE ] [ TILE ] [ TILE ] [ TILE ] | //Full Width

| [ TILE ] [ TILE ] [ TILE ]          | //Lower Screen Resolution
| [ TILE ]                            |
```

What I'd Like is:

```
| [ TILE ] [ TILE ] [ TILE ] [ TILE ] | //Full Width

|      [ TILE ] [ TILE ] [ TILE ]     | //Lower Screen Resolution
|      [ TILE ]                       |
```

I've tried using inline-block as suggested in previous posts but this doesn't work here, perhaps due to the "Tile's" being floated.  Is there a solution?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer using CSS3 media queries.  Just adjust the containing element's width to that of the number of elements it can hold.  My example is overly simplistic but gets the results you are looking for.

i.e. In my example the elements are 200px each total.  If the screen is 1000px wide then it could hold 5 elements across.  As soon as it is 959px wide it can no longer hold 5 elements across.  So we adjust it's width to what 4 elements would be, 800px.  You can continue to scale down or up as needed.

Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NzTPr/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="block">
          content
     </div>
     <div class="block">
          content
     </div>
     <div class="block">
          content
     </div>
     <div class="block">
          content
     </div>
     <div class="block">
          content
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
     width: 1000px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
     width: 190px;
     margin: 5px;
     background-color: green;
     float: left;
     color: white;
}

     @media screen and (max-width: 959px) {  
          .container {
               width: 800px;
          }
     }
     @media screen and (max-width: 759px) {  
          .container {
               width: 600px;
          }
     }
     @media screen and (max-width: 559px) {  
          .container {
               width: 400px;
          }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm wanting to use @media for other parts of this website and this has really helped me to understand it better. My problem is now sorted too.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To use `inline-block` with `text-align: center` on the parent element, you'll need to remove the `float` property.

However, you'll find that `inline-block` does what you are using `float` for - so you won't miss the float at all.

Here is a really basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/ppsHy/